# How can I get the source line number in error stack trace of a jar created by ant build?

Tags: java, ant, jar, javac

I am using ant to build a jar of my project in eclipse. I deploy that jar on tomcat. But whenever an exception happen in my code (which is inside jar), the error stack trace comes but the line number does not come -- instead it says unknown source.

How can I get the line numbers in error stack trace?

Comment: Which JDK are you using?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to compile your jar with debug information. Specifically, you need to find the `javac` task that compiles the classes that you later jar and add a `debug="on"` attribute. Example:

```
<javac srcdir="${src}"
     destdir="${build}"
     classpath="xyz.jar"
     debug="on"
     source="1.4" />
```

Full details can be found [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html).

Answer (score 6):

The attribute "debug" requires values of "true" or "false" and is translated to javac -g option.
When explicitly wanting to specify a argument to -g, you can do that by defining the
 attribute "debuglevel" , which accepts "source", "vars" and other values (see ant task 
documentation for more details). 
Setting debug="true" and debuglevel="source" will attach the source but won't provide line
 number informations, debuglevel="lines,vars,source" will give you the information
 that you need.